# Error: Cross origin null forbidden : ---Problem in downloading Open source contracts from Etherscan.io

Tags: web3js, contract-development, javascript, nodejs

**UPDATED:** 
I am trying to download source code of open source verified contract from Etherscan.io. Here is my procedure as directed by [Ann](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/77925/how-to-download-contracts-by-address-from-etherscan-using-web3-js). 
1. Download CSV file of captioned contracts.
2. Write following program to print source code of contract

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const csv = require('fast-csv')
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { window } = new jsdom.JSDOM(`...`);
var $ = require("jquery")(window);


var addresses = [];

fs.createReadStream('./osContracts/list.csv')
.pipe(csv.parse({ headers: true }))
.on('data', (data) => addresses.push(data))
.on('end', () => {
  console.log("There are address: ", addresses.length)
  for(i=0; i<addresses.length; i++){
    $.getJSON('https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=contract&action=getsourcecode&address='+addresses[i]+'&apikey=454BC5UXKPI2.............', function (adData) {
      console.log(adData)           
  });
  }
});
```

Here is my output

```
Error: Cross origin null forbidden
    at dispatchError (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\xhr-utils.js:54:19)
    at Object.validCORSHeaders (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\xhr-utils.js:66:5)
    at receiveResponse (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\xmlhttprequest.js:843:21)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\xmlhttprequest.js:678:38)
    at Request.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at Request.onRequestResponse (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\request\request.js:1066:10)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:583:27)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:115:17)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:456:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:309:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:290:11)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:182:23) undefined
Error: Cross origin null forbidden
    at dispatchError (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\xhr-utils.js:54:19)
    at ...........................................
```

**UPDATE:** 
also when i setTimout then following errors are also showing alongwith the previous ones...

```
{ status: '0', message: 'NOTOK', result: 'Invalid Address format' }
```

Comment: I'd recommend consolidating this into your original question, otherwise moderators might think it's a duplicate. You can edit the original post and put an **UPDATE** heading over it.

Comment: sorry, what "THIS" .... you are referring ?? .. means the last one ?

Comment: I am referring to this question. I think it's unlikely to get answered broken out from your original issue.

Comment: so should i post afresh with same data ?

Comment: Just update your original post.